# UNSAFE.putOrderedInt(this, stateOffset, NORMAL); in FutureTask

Tags: java, multithreading

What are the benefits of using "UNSAFE.putOrderedInt(this, stateOffset, NORMAL);"

In FutureTask class, the method to set outcome value is

```
    protected void set(V v) {
        if (UNSAFE.compareAndSwapInt(this, stateOffset, NEW, COMPLETING)) {
            outcome = v;
            UNSAFE.putOrderedInt(this, stateOffset, NORMAL); // final state
            finishCompletion();
        }
    }
```

i am confused about `UNSAFE.putOrderedInt(this, stateOffset, NORMAL);`why not change the state dirctly like this `state = NORMARL`,and use `putOrderedInt` method to modify the value is not immediately visible to other threads.
I don't understand what is the advantage of using `UNSAFE.putOrderedInt(this, stateOffset, NORMAL);`

Answer (score 1):

The benefit is performance.

A 'state = NORMAL' leads to a volatile store since 'state' is a volatile variable. The putOrderInt is a release store. On modern JDK's you will see that a 'STATE.setRelease(this, NORMAL);' is used. A volatile store is typically much more expensive than a release store because it has more strict memory ordering guarantees.

On the X86 a volatile store typically is followed by [StoreLoad] fence which causes subsequent loads to wait till the store buffer has been drained. And this can take time because the core can only commit the store to the coherent cache, once the cache line on the other cores has been invalidated. On the X86, every store is a release store, so you don't need any memory fences (the primary purpose is to control the JIT). And as a consequence, the core can execute more instructions per time unit.

Note: Correctly synchronized programs in Java can only have sequential consistent executions. For sequential consistency, the real-time order isn't relevant. So it doesn't make a lot of sense to talk in terms of 'immediately visible' since the Java memory model doesn't require it. If the real-time order is relevant, then you need to have a look at linearizability (which isn't part of the JMM). A volatile store will not make that store visible any faster to other cores compared to a release store; the store buffer is already being drained as fast as possible.